# No explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code did work but now it is telling me I have an explicit conversion in my return line.

```
public IEnumerable<Contacts> GetAllContacts()
{
    var Contacts = from c in dbc.Contacts select c;
    return (IEnumerable<Contact>)Contacts;
}
```

Comment: You've posted two questions now like this. Please include the *name* of the exception when you get one. And tell us the line number you get it on.

Comment: Do you have a class named Contacts? And a variable named Contacts? It's best not to call two different things by the same name.

Comment: Do you have two classes Contact and Contacts. Your return type is IEnumerable<Contacts> and your casting it as IEnumerable<Contact>. Or is this just a typo when you posted the question on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand the error message. It was actually (something like)

> Unable to implicitly convert type `System.IEnumerable<Contact>` to `System.IEnumerable<Contacts>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

Which means that you are trying to return an `IEnumerable<Contact>` when the method signature says `IEnumerable<Contacts>` (note the `s`).

The compiler is saying that you *could* explicitly cast to `IEnumerable<Contacts>` (a conversion exists) - not that you *are* explicitly converting.

So you need to change your cast to `(IEnumerable<Contacts>)Contacts`, to match the method signature, and the result of your LINQ query.